# Extract repository name from GitHub url in bash

Tags: bash, regex, github, regular-expressions, strings

Given ANY GitHub repository url string like:

```
git://github.com/some-user/my-repo.git
```

or

```
git@github.com:some-user/my-repo.git
```

or

```
https://github.com/some-user/my-repo.git
```

What is the best way in `bash` to extract the repository name `my-repo` from any of the following strings? The solution **MUST** work for all types of urls specified above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$ url=git://github.com/some-user/my-repo.git
$ basename=$(basename $url)
$ echo $basename
my-repo.git
$ filename=${basename%.*}
$ echo $filename
my-repo
$ extension=${basename##*.}
$ echo $extension
git
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to make it a one liner, but not working. REPO_NAME=${\`basename $REPO_URL\`%.*}

Comment: `echo $(basename "$url" ".${url##*.}")`.

Comment: +1. Is there anything similar to get the **hostname**, i.e. github.com, instead, @quanta?

Answer (score 25):

I'd go with `basename $URL .git`.

Comment: the best answer. The shortest as well

Answer (score 15):

Old post, but I faced the same problem recently.

The regex `^(https|git)(:\/\/|@)([^\/:]+)[\/:]([^\/:]+)\/(.+).git$` works for the three types of URL.

```
#!/bin/bash

# url="git://github.com/some-user/my-repo.git"
# url="https://github.com/some-user/my-repo.git"
url="git@github.com:some-user/my-repo.git"

re="^(https|git)(:\/\/|@)([^\/:]+)[\/:]([^\/:]+)\/(.+)(.git)*$"

if [[ $url =~ $re ]]; then    
    protocol=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    separator=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    hostname=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    user=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
    repo=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
fi
```

---

Explaination ([see it in action on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ivnDpU)):

- `^` matches the start of a string
- `(https|git)` matches and captures the characters `https` or `git`
- `(:\/\/|@)` matches and captures the characters `://` or `@`
- `([^\/:]+)` matches and captures one character or more that is not `/` nor `:`
- `[\/:]` matches one character that *is* `/` or `:`
- `([^\/:]+)` matches and captures one character or more that is not `/` nor `:`, yet again
- `[\/:]` matches the character `/`
- `(.+)` matches and captures one character or more
- `(.git)*` matches optional `.git` suffix at the end
- `$` matches the end of a string

This if far from perfect, as something like `https@github.com:some-user/my-repo.git` would match, but I think it's fine enough for extraction.

Comment: this is gold!

Comment: some urls don't have `.git` at the end.

Comment: @kenn: then they'd not be a valid remote for git, however. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#URLS.

Comment: I'm using an expanded version (play with it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/liVozi/1): `^((https?|ssh|git|ftps?):\/\/)?(([^\/@]+)@)?([^\/:]+)[\/:]([^\/:]+)\/(.+).git\/?$`, which better matches [the official spec for URLs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#URLS). Group 2 is the scheme, if missing the default is `ssh`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters nice, thanks. I added variables to capture group contents and made .git suffix optional:    


`^((?<protocol>https?|ssh|git|ftps?):\/\/)?((?<user>[^\/@]+)@)?(?<hostname>[^\/:]+)[\/:](?<pathHead>[^\/:]+)\/(?<pathTail>(.+)(.git)?\/?)$`, 


testable here:  https://regex101.com/r/NtqNET/1

Answer (score 6):

**Summing up:**

- Get url without (optional) suffix:

  ```
  url_without_suffix="${url%.*}"
  ```
- Get repository name:

  ```
  reponame="$(basename "${url_without_suffix}")"
  ```
- Get user (host) name afterwards:

  ```
  hostname="$(basename "${url_without_suffix%/${reponame}}")"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

use regular expression: `/([^/]+)\.git$/`

Answer (score 0):

```
basename $git_repo_url | tr -d ".git"
```

Answer (score 0):

basename is my favorite, but you can also use `sed`:

```
url=git://github.com/some-user/my-repo.git
reponame="$(echo $url | sed -r 's/.+\/([^.]+)(\.git)?/\1/')"
# reponame = "my-repo"
```

"sed" will delete all text until the last `/` + the `.git` extension (if exists), and will retain the match of group `\1` which is everything except dot `([^.]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Using Hitcham's awesome answer above allowed me to come up with this, using sed to output exactly what needed: `org/reponame` with sed.

```
output = echo ${git_url} | sed -nr  's/^(https|git)(:\/\/|@)([^\/:]+)[\/:]([^\/:]+)\/(.+).git$$/\4\/\3/p'`
```

Works well in ubuntu, doesn't work for the sed available by default on macosx.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to `@Hicham`'s answer

`^(https|git)(:\/\/|@)([^\/:]+)[\/:]([^\/:]+)\/(.+?)(\.git)?$`

Will extract out the .git suffix as well.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling half a day in regex101 and using input from @womble and the others..
I came up with this, which also has the capture names to denote what is handled where.. It may help even me in the neer future :P

```
/^((?<protocol>https?|ssh|git|ftps?):\/\/)?((?<user>[^\/@]+)@)?(?<host>[^\/:]+)[\/:](?<port>[^\/:]+)\/(?<path>.+\/)?(?<repo>.+?)(?<suffix>\.git[\/]?)?$/
```

it basically allows to use the repo name (see part ?) in a

.../reponame.git, .../reponame.git/, .../reponame and .../reponame/

repo url, as it handles the optional .git